# Path integral over a closed contour in the complex plane: $\oint \frac{1}{z-1} dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Suppose in the complex plane there is a circular contour $C$ of radius $R <1$ centered at the origin and it goes from $0$ to $2\pi$ anticlockwise. Then I got this path integral $\oint _C \frac{1}{z-1} dz$ whose path is along the contour mentioned. Since there is no singular point for $f(z) = z-1$ within the circle, by Cauchy integral theorem, the integral should be equal to zero i.e. $\oint _C \frac{1}{z-1} dz = 0$.

Now I would like to do the integral the manual way. Since $dz = d(z-1)$, I rewrite the interal as $\oint _C \frac{dz'}{z'}$. Using polar coordinate substitution $z' = Re^{i\theta}$, $dz' = iRe^{i\theta}d\theta$, the integral now becomes $\int ^{2\pi} _0 id\theta = 2\pi i$. So probably there are some problems with this. How do I evaluate the zero which is the actual result of this integral?

Comment: When you change  $z'=z-1$ this contour will be change

Comment: New contour $|z'+1|=\epsilon$